# Drawing a lot in short time period on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing, jpanel

I want to draw a lot of lines on JPanel in a short time period. Drawing by g.drawLine (in paint method) and then repaint is not efficient. What is best solution for that?

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you sure there are no bottlenecks in your code?

Comment: "not efficient" meaning ... ? What did you measure, experience ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think drawImage() and using BufferedImage is a good option. Am I right?

Comment: If you have a static image, then yes drawing the lines once on a buffered image is a good option.